# How to animate famo.us surface in Meteor

Tags: meteor, famo.us

I am using the famous-views package for Meteor, and I love it. I have created a simple UI with a few templates and a few surfaces and so on. Now I would like to do some simple animations. I would like to do something like this:

```
surface.on("click", function (e) {
  transform.setTransform(endPos, easeTransition);
  startPos = [endPos, endPos = startPos][0];
});

mainCtx.add(transform).add(surface);
```

The problem is, that surfaces were added automatically to the context, so I am unable to add transform *before* surfaces are added.

Comment: Can you not modify the surfaces during the Template.myTemplate.created or rendered callbacks? https://github.com/raix/Meteor-famono/issues/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your template**

```
<template name="appMainView">
    {{#Surface id="redbox" size="[250,350]" origin="[.5, .5]" align="[.5, .5]" class="redCard" modifier="Modifier"}}
        Click Me
    {{/Surface}}
</template>
```

**In your view (using coffeescript)**

```
Template.appMainView.rendered = ->
    mainContext = FView.byId 'mainCtx'
    mainContext.context.setPerspective 1000
    # transitionable object
    angleDegrees = new Famous.Transitionable -60

    isToggled = off
    defaultDegrees = angleDegrees.get()
    degreesToRadians = 0.0174533
    flag = off

    # red box code
    redBox = FView.byId 'redbox'
    redBoxSurface = redBox.surface
    redBoxModifier = redBox.modifier

    redBoxSurface.on 'click', =>
        if isToggled is on
            targetAngle = defaultDegrees
        else
            targetAngle = -defaultDegrees
        if angleDegrees.isActive()
            angleDegrees.halt()
        angleDegrees.set targetAngle, { duration: 2000, curve: 'easeInOut'}, =>
            console.log 'Transition completed!'
        isToggled = !isToggled

    redBoxModifier.transformFrom =>
        return Famous.Transform.rotateY angleDegrees.get() * degreesToRadians
```

See tutorial from http://www.tutas-labs.com/coding-lesson-2-animating-surfaces-using-the-transitionable/

Comment: Thanks. What an awesome tutorial for a noob like me.

Comment: no worries ... make sure you check out http://famo.us/docs/reference/pages/0.3/index.html 

You can put the examples in the Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
 // put famo.us code in here as js
}